# C# Copying a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, copy

I'm trying to copy dic1 to dic2, because I want to change dic1 without changing dic2. My code is:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> dic1;
private Dictionary<string, string> dic2;
```

Then after putting values in dic1:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dic2 = new Dictionary<string,string>(dic1);
```

But the values of dic2 are showing as null. How do I copy the contents of dic1 to dic2 and then clear dic1?

Comment: `dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string>(dic1);` You're probably creating a local `dic2`, then inspect the `dict2` Field, which has never been updated.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I have no trouble making it work using `new Dictionary<string,string>(dic1)` to copy the dictionary

Comment: `dic1` is null in your example and you are using it to initialize `dic2` so there will be no items in `dic2`.

Comment: If you do not have duplicate keys :  var dic3 = dic1.Concat(dic2).GroupBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and examined the value of `dic2` just after this line of code that initializes it? Do you now have two instances of a `dic2` member (one local to a method and the other a class field)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jimi points out in the comments, you are re-declaring the variable `dic2` when you precede it with a type. The following code is clearly class-level fields; I can tell this because they're prefixed with the `private` keyword:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> dic1;
private Dictionary<string, string> dic2;
```

So I'm assuming somewhere else in your class, in some function, you are using:

```
Dictionary<string,string> dic2 = new Dictionary<string,string>(dic1);
```

That is, as Jimi points out, redeclaring another local variable instead of setting the class level fields. To fix, and set the class-level field rather than an ephemeral local variable, just omit the type:

```
dic2 = new Dictionary<string,string>(dic1);
```

Answer (score -2):

Edit: I know this is not the best option. But it is another option.

```
Dictionary<string, string> first = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"1", "One"},
            {"2", "Two"},
            {"3", "Three"},
            {"4", "Four"},
            {"5", "Five"},
            {"6", "Six"},
            {"7", "Seven"},
            {"8", "Eight"},
            {"9", "Nine"},
            {"0", "Zero"}
        };

        Dictionary<string, string> second = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string key in first.Keys)
        {
            second.Add(key, first[key]);
        }

        first["1"] = "newone";
        // Printing the dictinaries
        Console.WriteLine("first dict");
        foreach ( string key in first.Keys)
        {
            Console.Write(first[key]+", ");
        }
        //newone, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Zero, 

        Console.WriteLine("\nsecond dict");
        foreach ( string key in second.Keys)
        {
            Console.Write(second[key]+", ");
        } 
        //One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Zero,
    }
```

Comment: Although this solution works, I wouldn't suggest manually iterating through the whole dictionary, when the constructor supports a dictionary to copy as input: `new Dictionary<string, string>(dictToCopy)`

Comment: The way the OP is initializing `dict2` is not a problem.